# Get graphviz to draw nodes above edges

Tags: graphviz, nodes, edges

Is there any way to force graphviz to always draw the nodes above edges even if the edge is drawn over (or preferably under) the node?

So far I have tried ordering them and different layer options but not found a way that works.

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to specify `outputorder="edgesfirst"`.  This can be found in the [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/outputorder/).

Comment: This didn't work for me.  outputMode is the name of the parameter class.  The name of the parameter is outputorder, so it's outputorder=edgesfirst.